# Edit a README.md File in Google Colab

Tags: python, github, github-actions, google-colaboratory

**Question:** Why can't I edit the README.md file in Google Colab?

**Background:** I've forked a Github Repo and I want to make updates to the README.md file and push back to Github. However, when I open README.md in Google Colab, I cannot edit it at all.

Comment: Is the file read-only?

Comment: @riQQ looks like it is not.... I used `!find . -type f -exec [ -r {} ] \; -exec [ ! -w {} ] \; -exec echo {} \;` to check.

Comment: I'm sorry @riQQ the first post I had it backwards - I've edited my comment now. It is NOT read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this problem as well. If you have a `.md` file in your file system, double-clicking it in the "Files" sidebar will bring up a read-only view of the rendered markdown content. Usually, when you double-click on a text file, a text editor will come up allowing you to edit the contents.

The simplest solution I found was simply to rename the `.md` file to `.txt`. For example, change `README.md` to `README.txt`. When you double-click it, the text editor will pop up. Remember to change the `.txt` back to `.md` when you are done editing.